# Ubuntu 13 Online Accounts keeps closing

Tags: empathy, online-accounts

Im on Ubuntu 13 now, whenever I open Online Accounts or Accounts in Empathy my accounts page comes up for a few seconds then closes, so I cant add accounts?

Tried restarting and running an update, still happens...

Comment: I have the same problem as of now. The program opens OK when my Facebook account is shown in Ubuntu Online Accounts. Then, if I click on my Google account, the program closes.

If I run `online-accounts-preferences`, I get the following error:

`ERROR:empathy-user-info.c:252:fill_contact_info_grid: assertion failed: (spec != NULL)
Aborted`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  This is a bug, and as such should be reported on [Ubuntu's Launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu), and not in Ask Ubuntu.  Thanks!